# ArcGIS Enterprise and Google GCE Hostnames/DNS Records

Tags: google, arcgis-enterprise, localhost

Has anyone installed ArcGIS Enterprise on a Google Compute Engine VM? I have successfully installed and configured it but am struggling with redirect errors when trying to log-in from outside the network.

I think it is related to the fact that GCE do not provide an external hostname, just an external IP. So to access from a local client I input my portal URL as https:/portal/home which can be reached in a browser just fine. When I attempt to sign in, it errors out and I believe this is because it's trying to redirect to the FQDN of the machine, which isn't external facing.

I have a client VM stood up in the same internal network as the Enterprise instance. From a browser on that client I am able to fully access portal, sign in, and all its features work. I think this is because the FQDN makes sense to it as it's internal only and this VM is in that internal network.

---

Solution? I think I need to...

- Set up a new GCE server VM with a custom hostname
- Configure a DNS record to that same custom hostname in Google Cloud DNS or similar
- Reinstall ArcGIS Enterprise on that machine and hope that it latches on to the custom hostname and not the internal hostname given by Google

Does this sound right? Anybody have any other solutions here? Don't want to spend a couple days down the rabbit hole.